# Is it okay to switch from SHA-1 to SHA-256?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am currently using SHA-1. I am using it like the following code, but I want to change it to SHA-256.

```html
public String sha1Encrypt(String str) {
  if(str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    return "";
  }

  String resultstr = "";

  try {

    java.security.MessageDigest sha1 = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    byte[] digest = sha1.digest(str.getBytes());

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<digest.length; i++) {
      sb.append(Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    resultstr = sb.toString();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    //error code   
  }

  return resultstr;
}
```

In this codes, I wonder if it is applicable simply to replace SHA-1 with SHA-256. Otherwise, how can i change SHA-1 to SHA-256?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That should work. You should also change `StringBuffer` to `StringBuilder`. And you shouldn't swallow `Exception`(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you. 
`Exception` seemed to have no need to show. 
Do not worry, actually, I did exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes changing the code to `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help.